# Continuous cycle of review test questions

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I've found interesting behavior in the review queue of first posts and late answers. If the queue gets empty during reviewing and I insist on getting the next item I do get a next item but it's a test (or audit) and if I try again another test appears and so on and on. I don't say this is wrong because keeping clicking to get a next item while knowing the queue is empty is stupid, but it's a remarkable behavior. B.T.W.: I haven't noticed this behavior before so it might be a temporary issue.